# SharpDX C# crossing axis with camera position or target causes roll

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d, sharpdx

Having difficulty understanding how to change the camera position or rotation correctly using  SharpDX in C#. I followed a tutorial that used the following to generate the necessary matrices:

```
var viewMatrix = Matrix.LookAtLH(camera.Position, camera.Target, Vector3.UnitY);
var projectionMatrix = Matrix.PerspectiveFovRH(0.78f, (float)bmp.PixelWidth / bmp.PixelHeight, 0.01f, 1.0f);  var worldMatrix = Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(mesh.Rotation.Y, mesh.Rotation.X, mesh.Rotation.Z) * Matrix.Translation(mesh.Position);
var transformMatrix = worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
var point = Project(vertex, transformMatrix);
```

I am able to set a point and move it. Once I also added a grid I saw that when the camera position was changed so that an axis was crossed (-10x to 10x for example) the camera would roll along the forward vector and everything would flip upside down. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am actually setting the position or target incorrectly. Instead of using:

```
Vector3 target = new Vector3(10,20,30);
```

Should I be using a quaternion? Or is this an issue of incorrectly setting up the matrices? The tutorial did not address this and I have also been having a random issue with setting the camera pos or rot to 0 for any axis as nothing will display. If you need to see more snippets of my code please let me know. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Any reason you use Left Handed LookAtLH and right Handed Perspective (eg : PerspectiveFovRH. ) This sounds a bit odd.